# Transform a smart object in photoshop dragged from illustrator - Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, transform, smartobject

Is there a work around to distorting a smart object using the transform tool that has been dragged directly from illustrator? I often need to show a graphic made in illustrator on a photograph of where it will be placed but I can't seem to ever distort it without rasterising the layer.

Did a test below of dragging vector shape from illustrator to photoshop and trying to distort but the option is greyed out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Photoshop**, if you wish to distort, warp, or use perspective distort, on a linked/embedded *vector smart object* (dragged in from Illustrator)....

First... convert the existing Vector Smart Object layer to an **new Smart Object** in Photoshop.

- Just highlight the vector smart object layer, and choose `Convert to Smart Object` from the **Layer Panel Menu**.

You can then warp or distort within Photoshop without rasterizing the vector smart object.

This *does* seem counterintuitive since the layer is already a smart object. I don't know *why* you need to double-nest the SO this way. However, it does work without rasterizing. It just takes more digging (tunneling) to get down to the original vector smart object.